# Friction and Newton's Laws of motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, friction, free-body-diagram, string

I came across the following problem.

[image]

Ok, I thought that assuming there is no friction between blocks B and C, when the blocks B and A will move, the block C will go to the right due to the force by the mass less pulley. I thought that the acceleration of B to the left will be numerically same as the **vertical acceleration of block A**, because there is no friction to oppose it. Just free motion. But it turned out that the acceleration of B gets affected by the acceleration of C.
And it is **acceleration of B if C was fixed - acceleration of C itself**.

My question is why is this so? What does B have to do with C and if they are not interacting by any means, then why would B get the acceleration of C?

Comment: They do interact. The string exerts a force on the pulley, which is attached to C.

Comment: my question is how does B get affected by C if they are not under friction with each other. C can get affected due to the pulley affecting it but how does B get affected by C without any friction or force as such ?

Comment: Are you familiar with problems such as pulley system in an elevator? If so, you will see that the overall motion of the system affects the motions of parts of that system.

Comment: understood....but here it makes no sense. Like see, if there are two block one over the other. But both are friction less . Now the lower block starts sliding. Can it give any acceleration to the upper block. No i guess, as it has no means to apply the force onto the upper one to accelerate it. I guess that after the lower block is gone the upper block simply topples and falls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

B and C do interact via the pulley.  It appears you're aware that the string is pushing on C (so that C accelerates to the right).  As forces arise in couples, this implies that the behavior of the rest of the system must depend on C.

In this case the motion of C also moves A horizontally.  Moving C to the right effectively moves A and B closer together.

If C were fixed, the descent of A requires B to move left by the same amount.  But if C can move, then less motion of B is needed.  In the limit, if we force C to move to the right with acceleration equal to $g$, then no motion (and no force) is required from B.  B will remain motionless.

Comment: ohhhhh my GOD.......thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

In the question it is given that the pulley is attached to block $C$ , so any force on pulley can affect the motion of block $C$

Now note that there's a tension in string (because of block $A$) and this tension in string pushes pulley as shown

[image]

This causes horizontal motion of block $C$ and increase the normal force on it.

Let vertical acceleration of $A$ be $v$, horizontal be $h$
acceleration of $B$ be $b$ and of $C$ be $c$

First apply string constraint

Let $l_1$ be horizontal length of string, $l_2$ be vertical length of string

$l_1+l_2=\text{constant}$

Differentiating we get

$v_1+v_2=0$ or $v_1=-v_2$ where $v_1$ is the rate at which $l_1$ decreases that is seperation between pulley and block $B$ decreases and $v_2$ the rate at which $l_2$ increases

differentiate both sides again

$a_1=-a_2$ where $a_1$ is the rate at which rate of decrease of $l_1$ changes and $a_2$=rate at which rate of increase of l1 changes

$a_1=b+c$ and $a_2=v$

Thus you get $v=-(b+c)$

Therefore it is clear that motion of $B$, $C$ and $A$ are interrelated

Comment: yeah but if a friction less thing slides over another does their individual accelerations affect each other.... i guess no.

Comment: @chittaranjanrout The string pushes pulley

Comment: see see...I get that the acceleration of C is due to the pulley. I've already said that. I do not understand that if C accelerates , why dos it affect the acceleration of B when it cannot impose any force onto it...like how will it..they are friction less after all.

Comment: @chittaranjanrout If you have any query, please write here

Comment: thanks for answering !